# Out of Range Exception with DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks

Tags: c#, .net, timespan, livecharts

Why am I getting this out of range exception, I used the same logic in framework 4.7 and never had this issue. Its running on 4.8 now, Is it something to do with that or am I missing something here. Someone please explain this to me.

```
pressureChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
            {
                DisableAnimations = true,
                LabelFormatter = value => new System.DateTime((long)value).ToString("mm:ss"), // Exception Here
                Separator =  new Separator
                {
                    Step = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Ticks
                }
            });
```

Exception

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.
Parameter name: ticks'
```

Comment: What is the value of `value`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks);  // =>  0
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks);  // =>  3155378975999999999
Console.WriteLine(long.MinValue);            // => -9223372036854775808
Console.WriteLine(long.MaxValue);            // =>  9223372036854775807
```

None of those limits changed in a recent release, so it seems, that you not having any exceptions so far, was just lucky or something changed in the calcuation of your `value`. By any means it can get negative? (either by accident or intended)